# Extract text from HTML file in bash

Tags: bash

I've got a large HTML page that contains this code line:

```
<span id="product542" price-amount="78.49" class="classname"><span class="price">78,49&nbsp;€</span></span>
```

I would like to extract the value "78.49" in bash. I'm trying in this way:

```
filename='./page.html'
curl link > $filename
number=$(xpath -q -e '//span[@id="product542"][1]/text()' $filename)
echo $number
```

but this returns a syntax error on the html file. How can I do? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: HTML is not XML and cannot be read by XML parsers (Unless it's XHTML, of course). `xmllint` has an `--html` option to use an alternate parser if that's an option.

Comment: `html2text` is a great utility. In you case `echo '<span id="product542" price-amount="78.49" class="classname"><span class="price">78,49&nbsp;€</span></span>' | html2text -` returns `78,49 €`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with grep command: `grep -Po "(?<=price-amount=\")[^\"]+" page.html`
Bash:

```
filename='./page.html'
curl link > $filename
number=$(grep -Po "(?<=price-amount=\")[^\"]+" $filename)
echo $number
```